# Разрешение экрана айфона в xcode 6

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день.

Обновил xcode до 6 версии. Если указываю deployment target 7.0, то в эмуляторе запускается как будто прога для 4 айфона, то есть с черными полосами сверху и снизу. Пробовал убрать галочку Use Size Classes, тоже не помогло.

Подскажите, как сейчас быть?

Comment: @abubakirov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Сталкивался с такой траблой, это причина не в xcode6, а, как ни странно, в лаунч имаджах. В ассетах должны быть все размеры лаунч имаджей. Просто добавьте их туда для каждого девайса, и все будет ок. Как ни странно :)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, не помогло. Можно инструкцию для новичков?
_____
Вру, все получилось. С размерами картинок напутал. Спасибо.